# Notepad++ - how to re-enable alt+n short-cut when closing tab

Tags: notepad++, keyboard-shortcuts

I recently upgraded to version 7.8.1 and now when I close a tab, I can no longer press alt+n to chose not to save the file and close the tab.

Is there a way to re-enable this functionality? I frequently open and close numerous tabs a day, so having to to press the right arrow key and then hit enter is actually a significant inconvenience.

In the past I could just hit ctrl+w and then alt+n to quickly close out the 10 tabs or so I had opened while working on a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **v7.8** release, the following [enhancement](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8/) was added

> Add “No to All” and “Yes to All” options in Save dialog.

The dialog box looks like this when <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> combination is used (*when multiple files are open*) :

[image: dialog_box_7.8]

However prior to this release (in **v7.7.1**), it looked like this :

[image]

The <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> shortcut no longer works (in case of multiple files) because the `No` button is no longer underlined. I am guessing that the windows keyboard shortcut `Alt + Underlined Letter` does not apply here due to two buttons starting with the same letter i.e `No` and `No to all`. (*See @Ken White's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58882544/notepad-how-to-re-enable-altn-short-cut-when-closing-tab/58886624#comment104040422_58886624) below for more clarity*)

To stick to the keyboard combination you are used to, you can revert back to **v7.7.1** or adapt to the current version with the new combination <kbd>Tab</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>→</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

---

If you are looking to close all files without saving changes, the new version provides `No to All` button, so you can do this instead :

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to **close all** files and then select `No to All`

---

The new change will be announced in the next release as the shortcut has been fixed in this [commit](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/commit/cf7e373dca890d65ecc86489fe9cce1bcc7597f7).

> Add shortcuts to Save or not dialog
>
> ALT-Y for Yes
>
> ALT-N for No
>
> ALT-C for Cancel
>
> ALT-A for Yes to all
>
> ALT-O for No to all

---

The new release [**v7.8.2**](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/downloads/v7.8.2/) includes the above change. (*Release Date: 2019-12-05*)

Comment: Windows allows buttons with captions that start with the same letter to still have accelerators. It's the responsibility of the developer to assign them. They do that by using an ampersand before the letter they want to act as an accelerator (which isn't displayed). For instance, `&No` uses `Alt+N` as an accelerator, and `N&o to All` would use `Alt+O`. If the NP++ developers failed to do so, someone should file a bug report.

Comment: Accepting answer because it provides information on how to solve this in the future.